# Does Visual Studio Express 2013 allow Entity Framework integration or not?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-exp-2013

This article [here](http://www.rssbus.com/kb/articles/ado-entityframework-manual.rst) says that the Express edition of Visual studio doesn't allow installation of third-part package Entity Framework, while this article mentions that i can use Visual Studio Express for Web 2013 to follow a tutorial that uses the entity framework.

Can I install the entity framework package in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web?

Comment: Are you aware there's now a free-to-use (for most uses) more fully-featured version of VS? I would recommend dropping the Express version, unless you have some compelling reason to keep it, and moving to VS Community.

Comment: Well, thank you for letting me know about this. I haven't thought of it before. However, I got a limited internet connection, so 20 GB download means a lot of time, the Express edition is only 4 GB

Comment: Your numbers are off, I think you're looking at required disk space for installation, rather than download size. But yeah, the Express versions are still smaller, that's a good point.